# Как получить в апплете timezone клиента?

Tags: java, applet

Получаю TimeZone клиента, как:

```
TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getDefault().getTimeZone("UTC")
```

Сижу во второй зоне, а получаю нулевую. Какие-то особенности в апплетах? Почему это не работает?

Вот у меня класс для получения формата теперь:

```
public class NetworkUtils {
    public static DateFormat ISO_DateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    static {
        TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getDefault();
        ISO_DateFormat.setTimeZone(zone);
    }
}
```

Ну и потом просто делаю так:

```
dateString = NetworkUtils.ISO_DateFormat.format(date);
```

zone показывает правильно, а в формате нулевая зона стоит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба метода `getDefault` и `getTimeZone` - статические. То есть при такой записи по факту вызывается только второй.

- `getDefault()` - возвращает местную зону для JVM
- `getTimeZone("UTC")` - вернет `UTC+00`

Вы определитесь, вам UTC или местную зону. И вызывайте либо то, либо то.

Comment: просто zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"); тоже  дает нулевую зону.

Comment: @Helena2977, так и должно быть. `TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")` должен возвращать нулевую зону.

Comment: вам нужно `zone = TimeZone.getDefault();`

Comment: И TimeZone.getDefault() возвращает мне нулевую зону тоже.

Comment: О теперь правильно возвращает, только почему-то когда я сажаю эту зону в формат, то в формате становится снова нулевая. Может я тут ошиблась? Сейчас напишу код класса вверху.

Comment: а `date` вы как создаете?

Comment: И у вас строка формата не верна. Вокруг `Z` кавычки не нужны, если вы хотите выводить зону.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так должен выглядеть класс для шаблона:

```
public class NetworkUtils {
public static DateFormat ISO_DateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
static {
    TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getDefault().getTimeZone("UTC");
    ISO_DateFormat.setTimeZone(zone);
}
```

}

Тогда время, которое приходит от системы, пересчитывается в UTC. Это мне собственно и надо было.